# colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark are ignored within application theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

(Note: This is somewhat related to [When using ActionMode, the status bar turns black on Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180091/when-using-actionmode-the-status-bar-turns-black-on-lollipop) so there might be some additional information there that I accidentally omitted from this question)

I have the following theme defined:

```
<style name="Material" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_green_dark</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/action_bar_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/secondary_text_color</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_green</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/secondary_text_color</item>

    <item name="textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>
    <item name="activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>

    <!-- ActionMode Styles -->
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Material.Widget.ActionMode</item>

    <!-- Global UI Assignments -->
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Material.Widget.Spinner</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Material.Widget.Button</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/Material.Widget.Checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>

    <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/Material.Window.Popup</item>

    <!-- ViewPager -->
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Material.Activity.Login.ViewPagerIndicator.CustomCircle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">?android:indeterminateProgressStyle</item>

    <!-- API 14+ (compatibility) -->
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_padding_left</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_padding_right</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_height_small</item>
</style>
```

I use this theme as follows:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:logo="@null"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Material"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.DetailActivity"
        android:label="Details"
        android:theme="@style/Material.Activity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

All of my activities derive from `NavigationDrawerActivity`:

```
/**
 * An {@link Activity} that supports a Navigation Drawer, which is a pull-out panel for navigation
 * menus. This drawer is pulled out from the left side of the screen (right side on RTL devices).
 */
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity
  implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

  private static final String LOGTAG = NavigationDrawerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private NavigationDrawerItemAdapter mAdapter;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  private NavigationDrawerItem[] mNavigationDrawerItems;

  private Toolbar mAppBar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// We have to call super.setContentView() here because BaseActivity redefines setContentView(),
// and we don't want to use that.
super.setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    setupNavigationDrawer();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  /**
   * Toggles the state of the navigation drawer (i.e. closes it if it's open, and opens it if
   * it's closed).
   */
  public void toggleNavigationDrawer() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
      closeNavigationDrawer();
    } else {
      openNavigationDrawer();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Opens the navigation drawer.
   */
  public void openNavigationDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  }

  /**
   * Closes the navigation drawer.
   */
  public void closeNavigationDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  }

  /**
   * Initializes items specific to the navigation drawer.
   */
  private void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wiw_green));

        mAppBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mAppBar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
          this,                  /* Our context (Activity that hosts this drawer) */
          mDrawerLayout,         /* The DrawerLayout where the nav drawer will be drawn */
          R.string.drawer_open,  /* Description of "open drawer", for accessibility */
          R.string.drawer_close  /* Description of "close drawer", for accessibility */
        ) {

          /**
           * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
           */
          public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
          }

          /**
           * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
           */
          public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
          }
        };

        mDrawerList = (ListView) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        mNavigationDrawerItems = buildNavDrawerItemsList();

        setupAdapter(mNavigationDrawerItems);

        setupNavigationDrawerHeader();

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View aView, int aPosition, long aId) {
        // Code not relevant
      }

      /**
       * Set the inner content view of this {@link NavigationDrawerActivity} to have a given layout.
       *
       * @param aLayoutId The id of the layout to load into the inner content view of this activity.
       */
      public void setDrawerContent(int aLayoutId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.drawer_content);
        inflater.inflate(aLayoutId, root);
      }  
    }
```

In `NavigationDrawerActivity`, I actually have to manually set the status bar background color (see the second line of `setupNavigationDrawer()`), rather than having it automatically set from `colorPrimaryDark` on Android 5.0 devices. Further, changing the color in either `colorPrimary` or `colorPrimaryDark` does *not* change the color of the status bar (although, this could be an effect from having `windowTranslucentStatus` set to `true`) or the `Toolbar` background color.

I'm wondering what I can do to alleviate this problem, as I think it's causing other problems in my Material-esque theme.

Comment: I got this idea from: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar which made me think that the status bar would be colored with `colorPrimaryDark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation that you cite is referring to the native Android 5.0 `Theme.Material`. `appcompat-v7` does not appear to be automatically applying any colors to the status bar, at least at this time.

So, for example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/MaterialColor), when run on an Android 5.0 device, gets the status bar color, because it is using `Theme.Material`. [This port of the same sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/ActionBarColor) to use `appcompat-v7` does not. [This revised version of the same sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/StatusBarColor) that uses `appcompat-v7` and specifically requests the status bar color change gets the color.

Comment: So, if using a navigation drawer, this automatic styling won't work _at all_, since you have to derive from an `AppCompat` theme?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301924/how-to-create-a-navigation-drawer-without-support-library for a reference on what I mean

Comment: @jwir3: You don't need to use `appcompat-v7` to use a navigation drawer. `DrawerLayout` itself works with any activity. The original `ActionBarDrawerToggle` that worked with the native action bar was deprecated, and the replacement requires `appcompat-v7`. So if you want to use the official non-deprecated toggle, you have to use `appcompat-v7`, which means that you have to set the status bar color yourself. Personally, I'd clone the `appcompat-v7` `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and port it to work on the native action bar, as I did with `MediaRouteActionProvider`, but that's just me. :-)